# ps and jcmd <PID> VM.native_memory showing different results

Tags: java, linux, docker, jcmd

I am getting out of memory issues while running docker container after a certain amount of time. I tried to investigate using `jcmd 305 VM.native_memory` to see what part of memory is causing this. It gives the following result,

```
Native Memory tracking:

Total: reserved=5888920KB, committed=1545948KB
Java Heap (reserved=4091904KB, committed=988160KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=4091904KB, committed=988160KB) 
 
 Class (reserved=1138672KB, committed=101896KB)
                            (classes #16457)
                            (malloc=6128KB #40571) 
                            (mmap: reserved=1132544KB, committed=95768KB) 
 
 Thread (reserved=131925KB, committed=131925KB)
                            (thread #94)
                            (stack: reserved=131444KB, committed=131444KB)
                            (malloc=307KB #469) 
                            (arena=174KB #185)
 
 Code (reserved=261762KB, committed=70338KB)
                            (malloc=12162KB #16615) 
                            (mmap: reserved=249600KB, committed=58176KB) 
 
 GC (reserved=152978KB, committed=141950KB)
                            (malloc=3474KB #385) 
                            (mmap: reserved=149504KB, committed=138476KB) 
 
 Compiler (reserved=474KB, committed=474KB)
                            (malloc=344KB #1431) 
                            (arena=131KB #5)
 
 Internal (reserved=83136KB, committed=83136KB)
                            (malloc=83104KB #24954) 
                            (mmap: reserved=32KB, committed=32KB) 
 
 Symbol (reserved=21183KB, committed=21183KB)
                            (malloc=18426KB #177513) 
                            (arena=2757KB #1)
 
 Native Memory Tracking (reserved=4118KB, committed=4118KB)
                            (malloc=16KB #192) 
                            (tracking overhead=4101KB)
 
 Arena Chunk (reserved=2767KB, committed=2767KB)
                            (malloc=2767KB)
```

The above results are fine as I have allocated 4GB RAM to each container and committed memory is committed=1545948KB or 1.5GB
But when I run `ps -o pid,user,vsz,rss,comm,args` it gives me below result,

```
PID   USER     VSZ  RSS  COMMAND          COMMAND
305 root      13g 3.8g java             java -XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/var/tmp/java/cleanup_old_
```

Here we can see the process (PID 305) is taking 3.8g of RSS memory. Why this difference is there? And what should I investigate/fix to see where this memory wastage/difference is coming from?

Comment: Did you ever find more info about this?